# PDO object's length greater than expected

Tags: php, object, pdo

I would like to create Javascript arrays with some data from a PDO object. Here is my code:

```
$req = $bdd->query('SELECT 
    id AS user_id, 
    fname AS user_fname, 
    lname AS user_lname
    FROM mand_users');

$autocomplete_users = '<script type="text/javascript"> var names_users = new Array(';
$users_ids = 'var users_ids = new Array(';

$i = -1;

while ($donnees = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    print_r($donnees);
    $i++;

    $user_full_name = $donnees['user_fname'].' '.$donnees['user_lname'];
    $user_id = $donnees['user_id'];

              if ( $i < count($donnees)-1) {

        $autocomplete_users .= $user_full_name.', ';
        $users_ids .= $user_id.', ';

           } else  {

        $autocomplete_users .= $user_full_name.');';
        $users_ids .= $user_id.');';

    }
}

echo $autocomplete_users . $users_ids .'</script>';
```

`print_r` returns

```
Array
(
    [user_id] => 1
    [user_fname] => Bob
    [user_lname] => Smith
)
Array
(
    [user_id] => 2
    [user_fname] => Alice
    [user_lname] => Smith
)
```

so the object's length would be 2. In this case, the JS code would look like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var names_users = new Array(Bob Smith, Alice Smith);
var users_ids = new Array(1, 2); 
</script>
```

but instead I get this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var names_users = new Array(Bob Smith, Alice Smith, var users_ids = new Array(1, 2, </script>
```

which means that the code in the `else`is not executed. So I checked the object's length with `count()` and it returned 3. How could you explain this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do not write your code like that it is too much error prone.
You could insert your data in 2 arrays, then you can use something like http://ca.php.net/implode to add comas..

```
$user_ids = array();
$user_names = array();

while ($donnees = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $name = $donnees['user_fname'].' '.$donnees['user_lname'];
    $id = $donnees['user_id'];

    $user_ids[] = $id;
    $user_names[] = $name;
}

<script>
var names = new Array('<?php implode("', '", $user_names); ?>');
var ids = new Array(<?php implode(", ", $user_ids); ?>);
</script>

(code not tested, just to give you a hint)
```

But to be honest, you should not do that, you should try to check out JSON :
http://ca.php.net/json_encode
http://ca.php.net/json_decode

It is the easiest way to pass objects tojavascript.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try this.

Answer (score 1):

$donnees doesn't hold all of the results at once, it only holds one result each iteration through the while loop.  When you're getting a count of 3, it's because it has 3 fields (user_id, user_fname, user_lname).  If your query returned 100 rows, your count would still produce 3 because you're counting the wrong thing.

You'd be better off creating an array for each list you want to create, populate that without worrying which is the last entry, and then after the while loop doing this:

```
$autocomplete_users = '<script type="text/javascript"> var names_users = new Array(';
$autocomplete_users .= implode(', ', $autocomplete_users_array);
$autocomplete_users .= ');';
```

... or maybe even better off just building the array in PHP and then using json_encode().